# Android numberDecimal not Working

Tags: java, android

I've tried the suggestions:

```
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"

android:inputType="numberDecimal"

android:inputType="number"

android:digits="0123456789.,"
```

but no one works to allow "." or "," digits

Anyone can help

Comment: Try this: `<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />`

Comment: On which type of field are you using this? Which numbers do you except to work and which actually do?

Comment: ``android:ems="10" android:inputType="numberDecimal"`` is already, and nothing..

Comment: @Ch4t4r in a ``EditText``, my code is equal of the Malus Jan (except styles, color constraints etc..) i want to allow digits of money ex: ``13,50`` or ``13.50``

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using `setInputType()` on the EditText or adding a filter to it somewhere in your code? Otherwise it wouldn't make any sense for this not to work.

Comment: @Ch4t4r i was not knowing about ``setInputType`` but set to ``inputValor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);``  and still not works

Comment: Having the same problem ever found a solution?

Comment: @Sheppy did you try the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two attributes(*android:inputType* and *android:digits*) to your editText, like this:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:digits="0123456789.,"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,." />
```

Comment: do not works, and show-me only the numbers, not all "text"

Comment: Please clarify your question.